System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Volume not found: default'
This is where I get the error:
await memo.ImportDocumentAsync(path, steps: Microsoft.KernelMemory.Constants.PipelineWithSummary);


The code includes:
           string modelsPath = @"C:\rahul\Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct.Q2_K.gguf";

           LLama.Common.InferenceParams infParams = new() { AntiPrompts = ["\n\n"] };
           LLamaSharpConfig lsConfig = new(modelsPath) { DefaultInferenceParams = infParams };
           SearchClientConfig searchClientConfig = new()
           {
               MaxMatchesCount = 1,
               AnswerTokens = 100,
           };

           TextPartitioningOptions parseOptions = new()
           {
               MaxTokensPerParagraph = 300,
               MaxTokensPerLine = 100,
               OverlappingTokens = 30
           };
 
IKernelMemory memo = new KernelMemoryBuilder()
    .WithLLamaSharpDefaults(lsConfig)
    .WithSearchClientConfig(searchClientConfig)
    .With(parseOptions)
   .Build();

using LLama.Common;
using LLama;
using LLamaSharp.KernelMemory;
using Microsoft.KernelMemory.Configuration;
using Microsoft.KernelMemory;

Tried fixing file naming and directories and I also tried the below, but it gives the same error:
await memo.ImportWebPageAsync("https://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/ftp/cats/J/A+A/ReadMe.txt", steps: Microsoft.KernelMemory.Constants.PipelineWithoutSummary);

